# Include Jar dependency in tar assembly using maven

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm building a tar.gz assembly using a custom assembly.xml file with the maven-assembly-plugin. Within that tar is {stuff +} a WAR file, with a certain dependency currently in:

```
WEB-INF/lib/my-dependency.jar
```

That all works fine.

Now I want to take that dependency, and remove it from the WAR file, and put it into the root of the tar.gz instead.

**Current incorrect solution**

I can get as far as putting the dependency into the tar, but I can't remove it from the war (using my current solution)

```
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <outputDirectory>/config/lib</outputDirectory>
        <directory>${project.build.directory}/fa/WEB-INF/lib</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>my-dependency-*.jar</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

To fix the above, I need some way to also delete ${project.build.directory}/fa/WEB-INF/lib/my-dependency-*.jar within the assembly plugin BEFORE the WAR is created... (I'm pretty sure it's already created by the time the above directive is executed.

Alternatively another approach may be better

Answer (score 0):

If the war is a dependency of this project, you may use the assembly plugin to unpack it and repack without the jars.  The key config is the unpack and unpackOptions properties.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
<id>my-stripped-war</id>

<formats>
    <format>war</format>
</formats>    

<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <useTransitiveDependencies>false</useTransitiveDependencies>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <includes>
            <include>*:war</include>  <!-- however specific you need here -->
        </includes>
        <unpack>true</unpack>
        <unpackOptions>
            <excludes>
                <!-- jars to exclude here -->
            </excludes>
        </unpackOptions>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Then, in your current assembly descriptor, you pull in this stripped war using file or fileSet.  If the stripped war should be attached to the project you just add this descriptor to the assembly plugin  element before your current one; if it should not be attached use multiple assembly plugin executions and set `<attach>` to false for the stripped war execution.

If the war is being built as part of this project, try using the `<packagingExcludes>` element in the war plugin config to keep the unwanted jars out of the war.  You wouldn't need an extra assembly descriptor.